# Should I be installing virtualenvwrapper globally?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am completely new to python and I want to learn Django.  While following the Django get started tutorial, it says I need to install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`, which I don't know if I've done correctly.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04

I successfully ran the command `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.

I ran the command `pip3 install virtualenv` as per this [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/) and the command `python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/djangodev` as per this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/contributing/).  The result was a directory `/home/john/.virtualenvs`.

I ran the command `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`.  The result was the file `/home/john/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.  However, the [documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) suggests I should see `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, which is not my case.

Before I possibly lose countless hours troubleshooting django/python bugs due to environment configuration issues, I'd like to know whether `virtualenvwrapper` is typically installed at a more global level?  Based on some things I've read, it seems like `.virtualenv` is similar to nodejs `node_modules` folder, where I can choose to install packages locally for a specific project or globally for all projects.  And it seems like `virtualenvwrapper` offers extra utilities that I will be using at a global level. Hence my hesitation and doubt on whether I'm configuring my environment properly.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, you certainly wouldn't want virtualenvwrapper installed in a virtualenv - it makes no sense as it is supposed to make using a virtualenv easier. I would suggest avoiding virtualenvwrapper for now - just get your head around the built-in virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

> I ran the command `pip3 install virtualenv`.

It's ok.

> The result was a directory `/home/john/.virtualenvs`.

No, the directory `~/.virtualenvs` is created by `virtualenvwrapper`, usually by the first call to `mkvirtualenv`.

> I ran the command `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`. The result was the file `/home/john/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

Well, I think the actual command was `pip3 install --user virtualenvwrapper`, that's why `virtualenvwrapper` is installed in `~/.local/bin/` (and `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y).

There is nothing wrong in user install. If you're not going to use `virtualenvwrapper` as root and will always run it as a user the installation is perfectly ok. Source `~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in your `.bashrc` and you're done.